# Added an else statement inside a for loop, and now only the else part prints even when if is true

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, if-statement

This is my first ever computer science course so forgive me if this answer is really obvious. I wrote the below code and it worked just fine. I just needed to add an else statement to account for an invalid name input.

Here is is before:

```
    mynames = ['Naomi', 'James', 'Amos', 'Alex', 'Bobbie', 'Josephus', 'Fred', 'Camina', 'Julie', 'Prax', 'Christien', 'Anderson', 'Havelock', 'Ashford', 'Bull', 'Anna', 'Arjun', 'Souther', 'Carissa', 'Samara']
    myscores = [89, 98, 76, 76, 84, 93, 82, 64, 63, 75, 76, 86, 96, 75, 86, 100, 99, 87, 84, 94]

    name = input("Please enter a name:")
    #search through mynames to find the name
    while name!='q':
        for x in range(20):
            if mynames[x] == name:
                 print(mynames[x], "scored", myscores[x])
        name = input("Please enter a name:")
```

And here it is after:

```
     mynames = ['Naomi', 'James', 'Amos', 'Alex', 'Bobbie', 'Josephus', 'Fred', 'Camina', 'Julie', 'Prax', 'Christien', 'Anderson', 'Havelock', 'Ashford', 'Bull', 'Anna', 'Arjun', 'Souther', 'Carissa', 'Samara']
    myscores = [89, 98, 76, 76, 84, 93, 82, 64, 63, 75, 76, 86, 96, 75, 86, 100, 99, 87, 84, 94]

    name = input("Please enter a name:")
    #search through mynames to find the name
    while name!='q':
        for x in range(20):
            if mynames[x] == name:
                print(mynames[x], "scored", myscores[x])
            else:
                print("That name is not in this class.")
                name = input("Please enter a name:")
        name = input("Please enter a name:")
```

It just keeps printing "That name is not in this class." no matter what I type in. SOS

Comment: It keeps printing that because it executes the `else` fore every iteration of the loop in which `mynames[x] != name`.

Comment: Did you ever try entering `Naomi`?

Comment: You should consider using a dictionary. `dict(zip(mynames, myscores))` will create one from your lists. It's much easier to look values up from there.

Comment: Take a step back from the python and just think about the logic.  Your code is currently asking for a `name`, if that name is not `q`, then it checks to see if the first index of the `mynames` list is the same as the name. If it is not, it says the name is not in the class.  Does it help to think about it that way?

Answer (score 0):

The `if` statement is evaluated each time through the loop, so you need to keep track of whether the name has been found, and then only print at the end.

For example:

```py
    while name!='q':
        found = False
        for x in range(20):
            if mynames[x] == name:
                print(mynames[x], "scored", myscores[x])
                found = True
                break
         if not found:
             print("That name is not in this class.")
         name = input("Please enter a name:")
```

Comment: You don't have to keep a `found` flag. Python has a special `for..else` construct for this.

Comment: That's a good point, though I thought the `found` flag might be a bit easier to understand for someone new to programming

Answer (score 0):

I think you will really benefit here from using a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries). See the following example.

```py
mynames = ['Naomi', 'James', 'Amos', 'Alex', 'Bobbie', 'Josephus', 'Fred', 'Camina', 'Julie', 'Prax', 'Christien', 'Anderson', 'Havelock', 'Ashford', 'Bull', 'Anna', 'Arjun', 'Souther', 'Carissa', 'Samara']
myscores = [89, 98, 76, 76, 84, 93, 82, 64, 63, 75, 76, 86, 96, 75, 86, 100, 99, 87, 84, 94]
name_score_map = dict(zip(mynames, myscores))

name = input("Please enter a name:")
#search through mynames to find the name
while name!='q':
    if name in name_score_map:
        print(name, "scored", name_score_map[name])
    else:
        print("That name is not in this class.")
    name = input("Please enter a name:")
```

In the first line, we construct a dictionary that maps the name of a student to the score they got. This takes away the need to iterate through the `mynames` list to see if a name is in it and then using the corresponding index to grab the score. This, in effect, removes the issue you were facing with `print("That name is not in this class.")` executing for every iteration in which `mynames[x] != name`.

We can then check if the name has a score by seeing if the name is in `name_score_map`.  This reduces the time complexity of the search from O(n) to O(1).  We can then grab score simply by using the name as a key to the `name_score_map` dictionary.